# Tailwind css Grid is not working in Reactjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid, tailwind-css

Here is an example of taiwind css grid working properly in HTML :
https://play.tailwindcss.com/mU6PzU0sqX

Despites, here is the same example in react, and it seems it does not pass:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-tailwind-playground-forked-m77pw?file=/src/App.tsx
See the not working component in the browser : https://m77pw.csb.app/

Here is the React code :

```
<div className="App">
      <h1 className="text-red-500">Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
            <div className="border col-span-1">
              1
            </div>
            <div className="border col-span-1">
              2
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your `tailwind.css` file does not contain the grid utilities, which explains why the styling isn't working.

Instead of copy/pasting Tailwind styles into a CSS file, it would be better to install Tailwind into your project. Installing Tailwind will generate custom CSS files that contain only the utilities you need, avoiding the need to ship massive CSS files to users and ensuring that all the utilities you use are available.

The Tailwind documentation has detailed information about [installing Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation), as well as a specific tutorial for [Create React App](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app).

If you are sure that you don't want to install Tailwind and wish to use a CSS file, see the Tailwind docs for [installing via CDN](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#using-tailwind-via-cdn). This will ensure the default utilities and variants are all enabled.

Comment: thank you
it seems that sometimes the  installed tailwind package does not take into account the 'grid grid-cols-{n}' syntax, when the purge option is set to true.

Comment: Do you know how to bypass this behavior ?

Comment: @FrédéricLang That would depend on how you're using the class and how you're configuring tailwind. This would probably be a separate question, but maybe check out the docs on writing purgable HTML? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production

Comment: yes, so : 
- when purge is off, everything work as expected
- when purge is on, the grid column template does not pass (in the contrary of other tailwind classes)
the behavior is a bit unexpected, but at the end you can make it work by disabling purge.

Comment: Of course, I don't use string concatenation in my class names

Comment: @FrédéricLang You might want to create a minimal reproduction and create a new question for that. I wouldn't suggest disabling purge since the file sizes get very large (unless you're using JIT where purge isn't used).

Comment: I followed your advice and created 2 minimals examples, one working and one not. Hope I will finally get an answer! : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67765561/tailwind-does-not-purge-as-expected

Comment: Missing grid utilities was my problem too - but caused by the Tailwind 2 JIT compiler not pulling them in without a restart of my CRA 4 project.

Answer (score 3):

This is also an issue when using **VueJS**.

It's caused by enabling purge for `.vue` files.

Solution is to disable purging for `.vue` files in `tailwind.config.js`

Perhaps your solution is to disable purging for '.jsx' files except in Production using environment variables.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30901385)

Comment: Not a new question

Comment: OP's question was about Tailwind not working in React, your answer is about Tailwind not working in VueJs. And while you edited your post by adding a reference to React the original question already has an accepted answer (from May 2021). If you take the time to read that answer you'll realize what you're describing here is an entirely different issue from the OP's one. So yes, you're answering a new question.

Comment: @lbsn This answer really helped because I was having the same issue. Stop this non-sense please.

Comment: Tell me about it @caravana_942, glad to have helped you out

Comment: @caravana_942 I never said this answer is not helpful. I'm just saying it's the answer to a different question and that question should be separately posted and answered (e.g with a VueJs tag instead of ReactJS, with VueJs in the title instead of ReactJS etc.) so that other VueJS users with the same issue can easily find it. Just my opinion, no bad intentions here.

Comment: @lbsn I get your point and it's totally fair. But the answer came naturally as a Vue.js answer and that is also great, I even found out my Vue answer on Google and got this link, everyone is happy :)

Answer (score 2):

Install tailwindcss with npm and make sure you include paths to your templates/components files in tailwind.config.js.

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Once we create the new folders and we want to implement Tailwinds that need to be included inside tailwind.config.js  https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's causing the problem in your case, but I was able to get it to work. I used the [Tailwind template for React](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-51kiy) on CodeSandbox. You can achieve the same on your local machine using [this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app) guide.

Here's a working CodeSandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-thunder-i1u46?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: great, it shows that the problem does not come from the tailwind syntax.
I know that grid is now a standard tailwind plugin only recently, maybe tailwind does not support it entirely ? 
for notice, I was able to make it work on my local machine with tailwind config 'purge' option at false.

Answer (score 1):

If you've followed the the [installation instructions](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app) on the Tailwind website then you need to make sure that you install [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) and change your `start` script of `package.json` to:

```
"start": "cross-env TAILWIND_MODE=watch craco start",
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check your index.css file,

If file contains Default CSS which comes out of the box just remove all the CSS and add below code in index.css file

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Hope this will solve your issue.